# SQLException: Incorrect syntax near 'bit'

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I have connect to SQL Server with JDBC. One of the queries I run has the datatype bit and when I run the program I get this error: SQLException: Incorrect syntax near 'bit'.

Here is my code:

```
            String sql3 = "SELECT DISTINCT customCategoryDescription FROM product_categories ORDER BY customCategoryDescription";
        rs2 = stmt3.executeQuery(sql3);

        while (rs2.next())
        {
            String customCategoryDescription = rs2.getString("customCategoryDescription");
            columns.add(customCategoryDescription);
        }
        rs2.close();
        stmt3.close();

        for(int i = 0; i < columns.size(); i++)
        {
            String sql4 = "ALTER TABLE transformed_table ADD "+columns.get(i)+" bit";
            stmt4.executeUpdate(sql4);
            stmt4.close();
        }
```

I tried the same query in SQL Server and the column was added succesfully.

Where is the problem?

Comment: You should edit your question and print out `sql4` after variable substitution.

Comment: @GordonLinoff ALTER TABLE transformed_table ADD B2B Solutions bit

Maybe the problem is because of the space character. But how can I delete this?

Comment: Place the column between rectangular brackets if there are spaces in the name of the column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is you have a value in customCategoryDescription that is an invalid column name -- like "NO SPACES", which means this:

```
String sql4 = "ALTER TABLE transformed_table ADD "+columns.get(i)+" bit";
```

will generate this:

```
ALTER TABLE transformed_table ADD NO SPACE bit;
```

If you do this (note the [ and ] ):

```
String sql4 = "ALTER TABLE transformed_table ADD ["+columns.get(i)+"] bit";

ALTER TABLE transformed_table ADD [NO SPACE] bit;
```

Comment: can I ask you one more question? I want to run these queries:      String sql9 = `SELECT 1 FROM transactions AS tr, product_categories AS pc WHERE payer_id = "+payer_ids.get(i)+" AND customCategoryDescription = ["+columns.get(j)+"] AND  tr.id_3rd_level = pc.id_3rd_level`;

String sql10 = `INSERT INTO transformed_table (["+columns.get(j)+"])`; but I get this error

But I get this message: SQLException: Invalid column name 'B2B Solutions'.

Can you help me?

Comment: @KonstantinaPapagiannopoulou - This question has been answered. If you have another issue please [ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You can always include a [link to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34694864/2144390) in your new question to provide context.

Comment: Your SELECT statement most like generates like this: 

`AND customCategoryDescription = [B2B Solutions]` 

But you want [B2B Solutions] to render with single-quote marks instead of square brackets. (Because in this case you are referencing a character value and not a column name like in your original question:

`AND customCategoryDescription = 'B2B Solutions'`